# Profile based configuration for js/Nodejs/ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, spring-boot, ecmascript-6

I've an application with ES6/js/react UI and Spring boot server side. In my config.js I have host server URL and other properties that changes based on Env. I can use spring active profile to pick up diff set of properties. How do I do similar thing on the js part?
The application is deployed as spring boot application with embedded Tomcat.

Another way to put the question is How can I do Spring profile equivalent in NodeJs/JavaScript world?

Comment: Do you have a build step for your JS? Babel? Webpack?

Comment: @ivarni We use Babel & Gulp

Comment: [This may](https://www.npmjs.com/package/properties-reader) be a solution, but I need a way to find which profile/property file to read based on the env Dev/Test/Prod

Comment: @Sïd Unfortunately, a question that doesn't show the code you have tried is not a good fit for SO. There are too many different valid ways to do it. If you tried it one way, and it didn't work, that would be a better question for this forum.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a server using nodejs to host your static files and act as a proxy server to your backend.

Lately I've used this [this](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) seed for my react-projects. I like it a lot, it uses webpack for building the frontend and also provideds you with a handy proxy server that you can use during development (which also gets rid of any CORS issues).

Settings for proxy server: [environments.js](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/blob/v3.0.0-alpha.2/config/environments.js)

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: @FrankerZ Why? I recommend using nodejs to create a proxy server during development with a link to an example setup on github.

Comment: Question and answer both are vague

Comment: @Juan Mendes, The question is how can I pick up config params such as URLs Db properties etc at run time based on the Env. Once I make the Spring boot jar file, I should be able to deploy it in any env and the program should pick up right config. I do this in the Spring-boot part using Spring profile. Don't know how to do it with the js UI part.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the need as you: how to use the same idea behind spring profile active environment variable. I used process.env:

```
const profile = process.env.NODEJS_PROFILES_ACTIVE;
```

I tested with Windows and Docker as an environment variable.

Comment: In Windows you should create an Environment variable with the NODEJS_PROFILES_ACTIVE using "Edit the system environment variables." For Linux the command: export the NODEJS_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev. And for Docker: docker run -e NODEJS_PROFILES_ACTIVE='dev' --name 'your_container' ...

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the following and it seems to work .

Set up files like config-dev.js, config-QA.js, config-prod.js . These hold the configuration specific to each environment

Ex config-dev.js

```
const config_params = {dburl:"mongodb://localhost/mydb", port:5000};
module.exports = config_params
```

Set up file - config.js which has the below logic

```
let loadmodule = "./config-" + process.env.profile + ".js";
const setting = require(loadmodule);
module.exports = setting;
```

In the index file or server.js,  import config.js

```
const config = require('./config.js');
```

Start the application as `'profile=dev node server.js'`